# Render HTML tag from Json response to template literals

Tags: javascript, html, template-literals

I am getting data from an API using Fetch with HTML tag in the JSON responses but after I render it on a page using template literals the tags are removed and the response is displayed in plain text.

Example JSON from the API:

```
"value" : {
        "key":"something < strong >keyword < /strong >"
      }
```

This is my fetch request and render:

```
fetch('www.someurltogetdata').then(response => {   if (! response.ok) {
 var counter = '< div>< h3 >Something went wrong, please try again</h3></div>';
 throw Error("Error")    }    
 return response.json();     }).then(data => {
    var html = data.value.map(data => {
    return `< div class="result">
    <a href=${data.url}>${data.content}</a></div >`
    }).join('')
```

//to render the HTML

```
document.querySelector('.someclass').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', html)
```

Desired result:

something **keyword**

but it's not working. The JSON value is rendered as plain text without  tag like this: something keyword

Please help me render json value with HTML tag?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new document fragment with [`createRange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createRange) and [`createContextualFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/createContextualFragment), and then append that to an existing element.

```js
const value = {
  key: 'something <strong>keyword</strong>'
};

let range = document.createRange()
const frag = range.createContextualFragment(value.key);

const div = document.querySelector('div');

div.appendChild(frag);
```

```html
<div />
```

Comment: Thank you, Andy! But I got a problem - I am getting hundreds of results from API and looping through a div using template literals. I created "range" and "frag" but don't know how to loop through my div. 

My current setup:
<div><a href=${value.key}>${value.key}</a> //this will create 100+ divs dynimacially with results from the API in each div
Now, I've created the frag but how do I replace ${value.key} with frag?
When I tried I was getting  - [object DocumentFragment] instead of actual content.